# Add Point from GeoJSON to OSM

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson

I have a GeoJSON with some points of interest that I would like to update to the Open Street Map project.
I cannot find documentation on Wiki to do so. Is it possible to import points to OSM from file?
Maybe I need to convert it into another format using `ogr2ogr` but I have no idea to start.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 4):

The [JOSM editor](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM) has a plugin called **geojson** that is able to open GeoJSON files. Install the plugin in JOSM and import the data as a layer.

Comment: That plugin seems to be discontinued since 2020, and new support still pending: https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/2372 .

Comment: The plugin project: https://github.com/JOSM/geojson doesn't have any [forks](https://github.com/JOSM/geojson/forks).

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to "is it possible" - one is "is it technically possible" but the other is the process that you need to go through to get community approval for the import.

That's documented in some detail at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines .  Among other things you'll need to discuss what you plan to do with the OSM community and show that the licence if any is appropriate for use within OSM.  You'll also need to merge the data with anything already in OSM.

Comment: I want to tag some installations (Air Quality Measurement Sites) I manage in order to update meta information.

Comment: Thanks - I'd still read through and follow https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines though.  I doubt that the licence will be an issue if you're in charge of it, but it'd be worth it to get the tags right first time and make sure that the data is conflated properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the JOSM plugin [geojson](https://github.com/JOSM/geojson) isn't available.

Instead, you can use this node CLI: https://github.com/tyrasd/geojsontoosm

```
$ npm install -g geojsontoosm
$ geojsontoosm file.geojson > file.osm
```

And the OSM file loads readily into JOSM.

---

There's also a Python CLI https://github.com/roelderickx/ogr2osm which looks much more capable. It requires a package called `gdal` to be installed, which takes a long time.

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can examining to imposm3.

https://github.com/omniscale/imposm3

Comment: In addition, the answer is wrong because imposm is converting data from OSM format into GIS format but the goal it to do the opposite.